# How would you change this code in order to retrieve the filepath without the filename?

Tags: sql, string, filepath

```
SELECT
LTRIM(
 RTRIM(
 REVERSE(
  SUBSTRING(
   REVERSE(FullFilePath),
  0,
   CHARINDEX('\', REVERSE(FullFilePath),0)
)
)
)
)
FROM FileSystem
```

This code was taken from http://www.kodyaz.com/articles/how-to-extract-filename-from-path-using-sql-functions.aspx  .

How would I change it in order to retrieve only the file path without the filename?

Comment: Tag your question with the database you are using.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try in following:

```
SELECT LEFT(FullFilePath, LEN(FullFilePath) - CHARINDEX('\', REVERSE(FullFilePath)) + 1)
```

**SAMPLE DATA**

```
CREATE TABLE #FileSystem (
  FileID int identity(1,1),
  FullFilePath nvarchar(1000)
)

INSERT INTO #FileSystem VALUES (
 N'D:\SQLDatabases\SQLSampleDatabase.mdf'
);
INSERT INTO #FileSystem VALUES (
 N'C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\100\Samples\License.rtf'
);
```

**OUTPUT**

```
D:\SQLDatabases\
C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\100\Samples\
```

Answer (score 1):

You want everything before the last `'\'`, so something like this:

```
select left(FullFilePath,
            len(FullFilePath) - charindex('\', reverse(FullFilePath) - 1)
           )
```

Answer (score 1):

```
Select REVERSE(
             SUBSTRING(REVERSE(FullFilePath),CHARINDEX('\',REVERSE(FullFilePath),0),
LEN(FullFilePath)))  
    FROM FileSystem
```

Try this, it works.